# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices Prophet Error

Tags: python, pandas, prophet

I want to implement prophet algorithm and use my dataset on the model.
After fit process i got following error in predict process.
How can i solve this problem.?

```
import pandas as pd
import pystan
from prophet import Prophet
df_prophet = df[['date', 'rate']]
train_df = df_prophet[:-5]
train_df.columns = ['ds', 'y']
train_df['ds']= to_datetime(train_df['ds'])
model = Prophet()
model.fit(train_df)
test_df = df_prophet[-5:][['date']]
test_list = to_datetime(test_df.date).values
forecast = model.predict(test_list)
```

> ---> 11     forecast = model.predict(test_list)
>
> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
> numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nice attempt. You just need a few tweaks.

1. By passing `to_datetime(test_df.date).values` you were creating a numpy array instead of a dataframe. `Prophet` expects a dataframe.
2. The `Prophet` model and predictor expects columns labeled `ds` and `y` and you're changing the column names after you split the dataframe, so your test part isn't getting the columns renamed.
3. You shouldn't need to import `pystan` since the Prophet module is built on it already.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from prophet import Prophet

df_prophet = df[['Date', 'Volume']]
df_prophet.columns = ['ds', 'y']
train_df = df_prophet[:-5]
train_df['ds']= pd.to_datetime(train_df['ds'])
model = Prophet()
model.fit(train_df)
test_df = df_prophet[-5:][['ds']]
forecast = model.predict(test_df)
forecast
```